# Rails Custom Validation Across multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a rails app with the following user models:

Truck
User

A truck belongs to a user with the following association:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :primary_crew_member, :foreign_key => :primary_crew_member_id, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :secondary_crew_member, :foreign_key => :secondary_crew_member_id, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

On the `Truck` model i have validations in place to ensure that the `primary_crew_member_id` and `secondary_crew_member_id` is always present as a `Truck` cannot have no users/crew.

What I want to be able to do is the following:

- validate that the primary or secondary crew member (user) is not assigned to any other truck
- expanding on that validation I need to make sure if John Doe on Truck A is the Primary crew member he cannot be assigned to a Primary or Secondary slot on any other truck.
- expanding further John Doe should not be able to take both the Primary and Secondary slot on a given truck (dual rostering)

I've googled and have come up with a validation that validates the primary slot like so:

validate :primary_multiple_assignment

```
  def primary_multiple_assignment
      if Truck.has_primary(primary_crew_member_id)
        errors.add(:base, "User has already been assigned to another truck.")
      end
  end

  def self.has_primary(primary_crew_member_id)
      primary = Truck.where(primary_crew_member_id: primary_crew_member_id).first
      !primary.nil?
  end
```

This seems to work and I can make sure that no user is assigned to a primary slot in any truck besides a single one.  However I need to be able to meet my validation requirements as noted above.  So basically I'm trying to validate multiple columns in one single method but I'm not sure how that would work.

I've read the Rails custom validation guide and am pretty much stuck.  Any information you might have to help would be greatly appreciated.  In the meantime I will keep tinkering and googling to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it by using two kinds of validations:

```
# validate that the primary or secondary crew member (user) is not assigned to 
# any other truck
validates :primary_crew_member, uniqueness: true
validates :secondary_crew_member, uniqueness: true

# validate that the primary crew member can't be secondary crew member on any 
# truck (including current one)
validate :primary_not_to_be_secondary

# validate that the secondary crew member can't be primary crew member on any     
# truck (including current one)
validate :secondary_not_to_be_primary

def primary_not_to_be_secondary
  if Truck.where(secondary_crew_member_id: primary_crew_member_id).present?
      errors.add(:base, "Primary crew member already assigned as secondary crew member.")
  end
end

def secondary_not_to_be_primary
  if Truck.where(primary_crew_member_id: secondary_crew_member_id).present?
      errors.add(:base, "Secondary crew member already assigned as primary crew member.")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've come up with my own solution since then which handles some different edge cases I didn't think about.  Will post my answer soon.